# Trying to get property of non-object & Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, json

fruitget.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "ssl";
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

$sqlquery = $dbh->prepare("select id, fruitname, fruitcolor, fruitimage from fruits order by rand() limit 1");
$sqlquery->execute();
$result = $sqlquery->fetchAll();
$result = array("fruits"=>$result);
header("Content-type:application/json");
$jsonfile = json_encode($result);
echo $jsonfile;

?>
```

index.php

```
<?php

$jcontent = file_get_contents("fruitget.php");
$content = json_decode($jcontent);

?>

<div class="ad">
 <h1>Fruit of the Day</h1>
 <?php
 foreach ($content->fruits as $fruit) {
    echo '<span>' . $fruit->fruitcolor . ' ' .$fruit->fruitname . '</span>';
    echo "<img src='".$fruit->fruitimage."'width='300'/>";
 }
 ?>
```

Keep in mind that I'm just taking parts of the actual file so the code above is not the full file, but these parts are the current issue.

The error I'm getting is:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Week 3\Fruit\fruitads.php on line 44
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Week 3\Fruit\fruitads.php on line 44

Line 44 is

```
foreach ($content->fruits as $fruit) {
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks. This is for a class and it was copied exactly as the teacher portrayed it, no errors on their side with the foreach but there is on mine.

Comment: Is it so hard to check what you have in $content?? `var_dump($content);`

Comment: It's null. Why is it null?

Comment: Try to learn a little.... Now display what is in $jcontent and maybe you will finally see the light by yourself#

Answer (score -3):

file_get_contents needed to be a URL and not pointing to the direct file. That's why it was null. Question answered.